# Decode REST Url in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, rest, restkit

I'm creating a module that receive and `REST URL` and need to match a pattern and extract the parameters

For example:
the URL "http://Product/1" should match the pattern "http://Product/{productId:long}"
and return the `Dictionary` with `productId` as a key and "1" as the value in as long

Does anyone knows about a Framework for IPhone that does it, or at least some of it?

Comment: I'm not a regex expert. what can I do with it?

Comment: Have you take a look at RestKit ? Never used it, but I've heard of it multiple times.

Comment: @Guy Ephraim regex can  "match" (specify and recognize) strings. take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression. its powerful.

Comment: RestKit is doing the opposite of what I need, it can create URLs, i'm trying to parse them

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL` has a method `pathComponents`, which returns an array with all the different path components. That should help you get the integer part. To get the name I'd use the host method of the `NSURL`. The docs say, that it should work if the URL is properly formatted, might as well give it a try then.

All in all, no need to convert into a string, there seems to be plenty of methods to work out the components of the URL from the `NSURL` object itself.

Comment: you can look at `NSURLRequest` Object aswell , which takes String URL as input

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *path = [[@"path+with+spaces"
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: this is not even remotely relevant to my question.

Comment: i proposed it using NSString , but involves lot of coding ? see my other answer